# Is there a DTM available for free somewhere?

Tags: data, dem

To go a little bit further than the [semantic question regarding DEM/DTM/DSM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/what-is-the-difference-between-dem-dsm-and-dtm), I'd like to know if there is a free (of charges and use) **DTM** datasets? And what about resolution?

As far as I know,only DSM are available to public for free.

Comment: Where in the world do you need the information for?

Comment: There's some sample lidar data here: http://www.capcog.org/information-clearinghouse/geospatial-data/

Answer (score 4):

For a list of sources, see also here: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Global_datasets

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the UK there is the Ordnance Survey Land-Form PANORAMA dataset that is available as part of OS OpenData. It is available as a DTM or as contours. The DTM is designed for use at a scale of 1:50,000.

For more information, use the link below:

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/landformpanorama/

Comment: Hi James. Thanks for that information. Unfortunately, I live in France and IGN did not yet release its DTM for free - the free release of the BD ALti is minimum 250 m resolution. It takes time, but they are on a good way ...

Answer (score 3):

Unsure of your location, but you may want to try the USGS if you're in the US. I think resolution is variable based on location, but you may find something of use here:

http://seamless.usgs.gov/