# Viewing LIDAR data (.las) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, lidar, visualisation, liblas

Is there an easy path to visualizing LIDAR data in QGIS?

I have some USGS LIDAR data in .las format downloaded from http://lidar.cr.usgs.gov/. This means I have both the .las and metadata in .xml format. I am aware [liblas](http://liblas.org/utilities/las2ogr.html), but not how to apply it to this task. I am running on Ubuntu 11.04 with QGIS 1.7.0-Wroclaw.

A similar question for ArcGIS is:  [Converting LiDAR data to raster (DEM/DSM) for ArcGIS input?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/how-to-convert-las-to-grid-raster-for-arcgis-input). I just need to get a sense of this data and the registration. Conversion to a DEM would be OK if I can visualize it.

Comment: The lasview.exe tool ([README](http://lastools.org/download/lasview_README.txt)) that Bryce mentioned has a shorter [LAStools.org](http://lastools.org) URL now ... (-:

Comment: this is a old question, but still relevant, yet with old answers at the top. just a note here at the top: it pays off to scroll down for newer answers.

Answer (score 17):

[QGIS 3.18+](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/) supports point cloud visualisation natively.

Answer (score 8):

**Update**:

As stated in [Peter's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389539/16141): *QGIS 3.18+ supports point cloud visualisation natively*.

Some documentation for reference:

- [QGIS 3.18 changelog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/#point-clouds).
- [Installation guide](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2021/02/15/qgis-point-cloud-windows/).
- [The crowdfunding initiative](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/crowdfunding/pointcloud-qgis/).
- [List of contributors](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2021/02/18/qgis-3-18-point-cloud/) (with list of new features as well).

---

**Original answer:**

Additional alternatives to visualize LiDAR point data or LiDAR DEMs **within QGIS** were also reported in the following posts:

- [Visualizing a LiDAR point cloud in 3D with GRASS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137518/visualizing-a-lidar-point-cloud-in-3d-with-grass) - (GRASS; raster).
- [Importing LiDAR .txt in QGIS for map conversion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132676/importing-lidar-txt-in-qgis-for-map-conversion) - (QGIS; point .txt).
- [Importing a .las file into QGIS 2.0.1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83212/importing-a-las-file-into-qgis-2-0-1/83697#83697) - (QGIS; point .shp)
- [Creating DEM from LAS file without using LAStools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181712/creating-dem-from-las-file-without-using-lastools/181723#181723) - (SAGA and Fusion; raster/DEM).
- [Removing las2dem streaks from raster DEM?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152639/how-to-remove-las2dem-streaks-from-raster-dem) - (LAStools; raster/DEM)

Additionally, the following question asks for ongoing efforts in allowing LiDAR .las files to be visualized in the 2D main window in QGIS.

- [What is the status of any ongoing efforts that will allow QGIS to display .las files directly in the main 2D window?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112940/what-is-the-status-of-any-ongoing-efforts-that-will-allow-qgis-to-display-las-f)

Answer (score 5):

GRASS has a documentation section on LiDAR [in their wiki](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/LIDAR). Give it a read; you can use [libLAS](http://liblas.org/) to import LiDAR data into GRASS, and then use many of the GRASS tools once it's in there.

Comment: Is there anything more digested or step-by-step?  There are a lot of gaps to bridge there...

Comment: So far I'm having some good results with lasview.exe from http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/ , which is at least letting me verify the data is reasonably good.

Comment: GRASS 7 is offering v.in.lidar: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/html70_user/v.in.lidar.html

Comment: Hi Bryce, I don't know of anything more 'digested' and am far from a LiDAR expert. I suspect you should be able to piece some of that stuff together and at least get started, learning the rest as you go.

Comment: Lastools are a great candidate to be added to the QGIS processing framework. Anyone interested in supporting its implementation?

Comment: Consider including a reference to this [tutorial](http://courses.neteler.org/importing-and-visualizing-las-lidar-files-in-grass-gis-7-r-in-lidar/) in your answer. Tks.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [LAS toolbox](http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/) for QGIS. However, a better alternative for Linux/Unix systems is the open-source library [SPDLib](http://www.spdlib.org/doku.php). SPDLib can process the LAS files (discrete-return and full-waveform), and create DTM/DSM's from the point cloud.

To view the point cloud, the .las file must be converted to an SPD file (using the spdtranslate function), which can then be opened in SPD3DPointsViewer. The viewer itself also runs on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Use Point Cloud VIZ 2.1 where you will be able to import and export the lidar.  Exporting the lidar has 2 options.  The bare earth option, or all points options.  Once exported you can import the *.vrt file in QGIS.  The data will come as a geotiff where you will be able to manipulate further (contour, shade, etc.)

Comment: I can't find a way to open `las` files from the menu `File > Open processed files...`. It seems that the only files supported are `plf`.

Comment: Go to File > Process > Process Lidar Data.  There you will choose the LAS file that you want to process.  Once completed then you will go to Open Processed Files

Answer (score 4):

QGIS does not currently have a really good way to visualize point cloud data (i.e. as of 2018). Instead, I would recommend the excellent, open source [plas.io](http://plas.io/) web app. [plas.io](http://plas.io/) allows you to visualize the point cloud data with the ability to adjust particle size, point density, intensity, color, and a host of other features.

For example, the screenshot shows a point cloud visualization of Half Dome in Yosemite NP. I typically use the web app to visually scan the point cloud data to check for things such as scan line overlap and point density prior to processing.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I used GRASS in QGIS. Step to see LAS file are:
  (1) Processing on the menu bar
  (2) Toolbox
  (3) Find `v.in.lidar` or `r.in.lidar` under GRASS
  (4) Run

Version:
  QGIS Desktop 3.6.0
  GRASS 7.6.0
  OS: Windows 10

Comment: This steps work fine in QGIS 3.14, as of August, 2020.

Answer (score 1):

If you install QGIS with OSgeo4W then you can choose to add PDAL Library. It is a completely open source (not like LasTools). Then you can download model (within qgis) from internet using Pdal or you can use pdal from command line (the documentation : https://pdal.io/ and https://pdal.io/tutorial/reading.html).

Comment: Current (Nov 2019) osgeo4w pdal package has a compatibility problem. I had better luck installing with conda, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262321/how-to-install-pdal-in-windows, though that was for command line use and not within Qgis.