# What is the procedure to load LAS files in QGIS 2.0.1?

Tags: qgis, lidar

What is the present procedure to load LAS files in QGIS 2.0.1?

After some searching I found a paper outlining the procedure; however, it was for 1.8.something, and related posts here are all rather dated.

Comment: related question (QGIS 1.7): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19338/viewing-las-format-lidar-data-in-qgis?rq=1

Comment: LAS files are very specialised and really need fancy software to do stuff with them. You can use LASTools in QGIS with the extension for free and make surface DEMs etc. Then work with the resulting raster data as normal... My question would be what do you want to do with the data?

Answer (score 7):

A paid LAStools toolbox has been released for QGIS by [Rapidlasso GmbH](http://rapidlasso.com/). Instructions on installing it can be found at:

http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/

You can find the pricing information on this page: 
http://rapidlasso.com/pricing/

Comment: Great link to an amazing set of tools; though a link to their pricing and licensing should not be overlooked: http://rapidlasso.com/pricing/

Comment: Is the LAStools the only way to load an las file?