# Is it possible to load an .las file directly into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, lidar

Is it possible to load an .las file directly into QGIS?

I would like to be able to load LiDAR data and to be able to do analysis based various feature attributes; e.g., elevation, classifications, etc. While LASTools (which was suggested in [What is the procedure to load LAS files in QGIS 2.0.1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73252/what-is-the-procedure-to-load-las-files-in-qgis-2-0-1)) is a nice set of tools, it still didn't produce an .las point file that could be read by QGIS

Comment: Please check out http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19338/viewing-las-format-lidar-data-in-qgis similar question may it help.

Answer (score 1):

liblas can be compiled with gdal support, then use las2ogr to convert the las to a QGIS-supported vector format.
http://www.liblas.org/utilities/las2ogr.html