# Importing a .las file into QGIS 2.0.1?

Tags: qgis, import, lidar, las, lastools

I want to import a .las file into QGIS 2.0.1. My guess is that I need to convert it into a format that is readable in QGIS. But how?

I tried using LASTools. I downloaded it, but I don't understand how to use it? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make some screenshots?

Comment: I downloaded LASTools, but then I don't know what to do. Can't find a way to install it, and read somewhere that it didn't need to be installed? But, in that case, I don't understand what my next step would be?

Comment: I think you have to find the button where you convert your data into a shapefile, which can be opened by QGIS

Answer (score 2):

1) Open:

```
 las2shp.exe
```

to convert the data into shapefiles.

2)  Add them to a QGIS project by clicking "add vector layer"

Comment: Thanks for answering. I found las2shp.exe and opened it. Can you please walk me through how to make the coversion work? I chose an output directory, and then clicked 'Run'. Do I need to choose input somehow?

Comment: The input should be your .las file the output should be a .shp file. The conversion worked if you can add the shp file to your QGIS project.

Comment: Where in las2shp do I specify my input and output files? I don't get it to work.

Comment: There is a screen shot here: http://rapidlasso.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/arcgis_toolbox_las2shp.png

Comment: Perhaps I got an other version of las2shp, because it does not look anything like it does on that screenshot... Mine says version 140113?

Comment: I got it to run by using LAStools\bin\las2shp.exe into the run command window on windows, then manually typing into the directory the location of the LAS/LAZ file, then choose your outputs.