# Importing LiDAR .txt in QGIS for map conversion

Tags: qgis, coordinates, import, lidar, ascii

I have LiDAR data in .txt files (1000 to 26000 KB), where 2nd column marks x-coordinates, 3rd col y and 4th col z.

```
8 485000.16 6508997.48 1.84 66 Last
2 485001.27 6508998.92 1.86 82 Last
2 485001.02 6508996.68 1.85 23 Last
2 485000.77 6508994.45 1.79 36 Last
2 485000.52 6508992.19 1.79 10 Last
2 485000.02 6508987.69 1.74 80 Last
8 485000.23 6508974.93 1.89 107 Last
2 485001.02 6508981.87 1.86 47 Last
2 485001.54 6508986.50 1.72 19 Last
2 485002.32 6508993.34 1.72 1 Last
```

And I would like to convert it into a map, where I can model flooding. I've tried 'Add Delimited Text Layer...' but it gives me an error:

> records discarded due to invalid geometry definitions

Comment: I guess 2nd should be x, not z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding your data as delimited text works for me. You have to select a projected CRS for the layer.

It might be that additional blanks (or tabs) spoil the import in following data rows. If the error message does not reference a line number, you can use a good text editor like notepad++ to search and replace those.