# Visualize ASCII point cloud data in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have (lat, lon, z) point cloud data with a format similar to the data here:

[Importing LiDAR .txt in QGIS for map conversion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132676/importing-lidar-txt-in-qgis-for-map-conversion)

I want to view these data---not a model---from different camera angles. I suspect I can do so with QGIS's 3D mapping functionality but I haven't found out how to get the elevation (z coordinate) to display as the "up" direction. All the points display at what seems to be the same elevation and I can't zoom in very much. How might I do this?

Comment: More details please. A picture would help to explain what you mean by getting Z to "display as the 'up' direction."

Comment: Maybe try CloudCompare?  https://www.danielgm.net/cc/

Comment: "Up" is part of the QGIS GUI for 3D maps. See [here](https://imgur.com/a/D2i8O8W).

Comment: This must be done in QGIS or not at all :-(