# Removing las2dem streaks from raster DEM?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, lidar, lastools

I've created a series of DEM files using the [las2dem](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/las2dem_README.txt) tool from LAStools; however since I don't have a licensed version they have black streaks running across them. Does anyone know a good method for removing these streaks?

[image: Here's a screenshot of the issue...]

Comment: LAStools licensing is very reasonably priced compared to other software packages.  This is by far your best bet. Alternatively, use FUSION, which is free: http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Aaron, two options are:

i) acquiring a licensed version from LAStools which won't add the streaks in the DEM from the `las2dem` tool.

ii) using an alternative [free] software. For example:

- MCC-LiDAR:

  [Determining bare earth DEM from unclassified LAS file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101786/determining-bare-earth-from-unclassified-las-file/108342#108342)
- Fusion (running from QGIS):

  [Creating DEM from LAS file without using LAStools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181712/creating-dem-from-las-file-without-using-lastools/181723#181723)

---

iii) try using `blast2dem` tool (free version) as suggested in [LAStools' answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152639/removing-las2dem-streaks-from-raster-dem/295332#295332).

Answer (score 1):

PDAL's [`writers.gdal`](https://pdal.io/stages/writers.gdal.html) supports IDW-style interpolation which may be useful depending on the situation. The PDAL workshop provides [an exercise](https://pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/dtm/dtm.html) describing how to use it to create a DTM and a hillshade with [gdaldem](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [blast2dem](http://rapidlasso.com/blast2dem) tool instead of the [las2dem](http://rapidlasso.com/las2dem) which has a much higher "free" limit of 6 million points per file.

At the same time use smaller tiles and also pre-filter the tiles to contain only the points you are interested in (e.g. only class 2 points, only the highest points on a 1 meter grid, only the first returns, ... ).

Make sure you use [tiles with buffers](http://rapidlasso.com/2015/08/07/use-buffers-when-processing-lidar-in-tiles/) to avoid edge artifacts:

Comment: blast2dem point size limit appears to be 5M points not 6M. I used the blast tool  versus las2dem along with the pre filter suggestion of "keep classification" value of "2" (for ground points only) to get the point size under 5M points and it worked great. No stripes!