# Fill gaps in dem created from .laz file

Tags: dem, lidar

I've been trying to fill those lidar scan lines in my dem with no avail. Is there any way to interpolate those "gaps" to get a clean dem? I used las2dem to create the dem from .laz file
[image]

Comment: These lines are added by las2dem because you are using the free version.  Here is a previous post about this issue (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152639/how-to-remove-las2dem-streaks-from-raster-dem).