# How to install PDAL in Windows?

Tags: installation, lidar, windows, pdal

I want to import .las files to PostGIS. As I found out I can do it by using PDAL.

However, I cannot find the right way to install it in Windows. I downloaded a folder from here https://www.pdal.io/download.html, but then, I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You downloaded the source code, not a prebuilt binary.

If you read the [PDAL download](https://www.pdal.io/download.html) page you linked to you will see:

> ### Binaries
>
> ...
>
> #### Windows
>
> Windows builds are available via Conda Forge (64-bit only).

Install [Conda](https://conda.io/en/latest/) (or [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)), run a Conda shell, install PDAL with

```
conda install -c conda-forge pdal
```

and you should be good to go. See the [Conda instructions](https://pdal.io/download.html#conda) for more detail.