# Open source approach to classifying and removing LiDAR points from overlapping scans?

Tags: lidar, point-cloud, open-source-gis

The attached screenshot shows a LiDAR point cloud with significant overlapping scans. This point cloud tile is part of the [MN statewide LiDAR dataset](ftp://ftp.gisdata.state.mn.us/pub/data/elevation/lidar/q250k/) which has 25% scan overlap and 1.5 NPS. For many applications, these overlaps pose no problem. However, when calculating LiDAR metrics such as forestry grid metrics, these overlapping scan can pose a major problem by creating biases in the resulting products.

There are several commercial applications that can deal with these overlapping scans such as Esri's [Classify LAS Overlap](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/classify-las-overlap.htm) and Lastools [lasoverage](https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasoverage/). Is there an open source approach to detect, classify, and remove overlapping points from multiple flight lines?

[image]

Comment: Do the points have GPS time values?  If so, grouping by major chunks of time is one way to pull them apart.

Comment: I would just thin the entire point cloud to a fixed ground density.

Comment: BTW, if it is an las format, there should be a scan angle attribute. You could just threshold that value.

Comment: @HowardButler Yes, the laz files have GPS time stamps.

Comment: Do you want to discriminate between scans or simply have a consistent density?

Comment: @HowardButler A consistent density for calculating statistics within a grid would be most useful.

Comment: Also, if possible, try choosing metrics which are more stable to point density heterogeneity (which usually are the height metrics). See for example: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13595-015-0457-x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of options. Depending on the area of MN where you're processing, the overlap areas of the data are classified, and you can use a PDAL [filters.range](https://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.range.html) to cull them out:

```
pdal translate input.las output.las range --filters.range.limits="!Classification[12:12]"
```

[image: MN flightline overlap] (inspect and visualize that in your browser [here](http://speck.ly/?s=http%3A%2F%2Fc%5B0-7%5D.greyhound.io&r=mn-z&ca=0&ce=42.25&ct=-10369179%2C5434276.407%2C375.850&cd=19307.271&cmd=1900626.247&ps=2&pa=0.1&ze=1&c0s=local%3A%2F%2Ffield-color%3Ffield%3DClassification))

Not everywhere has these nicely classified, however, and [PDAL](https://pdal.io)'s [filters.sample](https://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.sample.html) would be one way to create a point cloud of consistent density.

```
pdal translate input.las output.las sample --filters.sample.radius=1.414
```

PDAL works on Windows, OSX, and Linux/Docker. You can find out how to install PDAL from [this SO post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/262334/350) or on the [PDAL website](https://www.pdal.io/workshop/osgeo4w.html#workshop-osgeo4w).

Comment: Revisiting this after a few years--great answer. FYI, the second and last links are 404.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest release of the open-source geoprocessing platform [WhiteboxTools](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/WhiteboxTools/index.html) (v. 0.7) I just added a new tool called **ClassifyOverlapPoints** that classifies or filters LAS points in regions of overlapping flight lines. If the *--filter* flag is specified, points from overlapping flightlines (i.e. later GPS times) are culled from the output point cloud. If this flag is left off, then all overlapping points are classified as such by setting the classification to 12 (see figures below, visualized using plas.io). This tool assumes that GPS data are available for the input LAS file. Scan angles are also utilized if present in the data set.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The library can be downloaded freely [here](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/WhiteboxTools/download.html) and the source code for the tool can be found [here](https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools/blob/master/src/tools/lidar_analysis/classify_overlap_points.rs). The [User Manual](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323547863_WhiteboxTools_User_Manual) contains information about how to use WhiteboxTools and the **ClassifyOverlapPoints** tool as do the [tutorials](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/WhiteboxTools/tutorials.html). The tool can either be called through Python scripting (see below), or using the simple **WhiteboxTools Runner** user interface:

```python
from WBT.whitebox_tools import WhiteboxTools

wbt = WhiteboxTools()

wbt.work_dir = "/path/to/data/"
in_file = "my_file.las"
out_file = "filtered.las"
wbt.classify_overlap_points(in_file, out_file, resolution=2.0, filter=False)
```

[image]

There is a [QGIS plugin for the library](https://plugins.bruy.me/processing-whitebox.html), but this tool is not yet available in the plugin. Other related tools that could also be useful for this type of analysis include **FilterLidarScanAngles**, **FlightlineOverlap**, **LidarPointDensity** and **LidarPointStats**.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @HowardButler's answer, the [`lidR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/lidR.pdf) package in R also has a method to filter out points already classified as "overlapping" using `readLAS()` (i.e. in the case of the MN dataset, overlapping points are classified as "17").

```
require(lidR)

# Check to see all available filters
rlas:::lasfilterusage()

# Read points != 17
las <- readLAS('path/to/data.laz', filter="-drop_class 17")
```

---

Figure 1 shows the filtered and unfiltered point cloud pulse density maps.

**Figure 1.**
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Great! Are you able to propose any solution when overlapping areas aren't classified? I suppose to filter GPS times or/and scan angles but have no idea specify these values.