# How to filter point cloud by flightline in R?

Tags: r, lidar, filter, point-cloud, lidr

The [`lidR`](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR) package in R provides a way to mark individual points in a point cloud with a flightline ID by using [`lasflightline()`](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/lasflightline). From the documentation:

> Retrieve each individual flightline by attributing a number to each
>   point. The function depends on the GPS time to retrieve each
>   individual flightline. In a continuous dataset, once points are
>   ordered by GPS time, the time between two consecutive points does not
>   exceed a few milliseconds. If the time between two consecutive points
>   is too long it means that the second point is from a different
>   flightline. The default threshold is 30 seconds. A column
>   'flightlineID' is added in the slot @data

How can one filter the resulting point cloud by the flightline ID so that overlapping points from different flightlines are removed from the filtered product? Essentially, I am looking to remove the overlapping points so as to produce a homogeneous point cloud with no scanline overlaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not natively possible yet in lidR! But R is a programming language so you can write your own algorithm to achieve this task. If you can do that please share with the community it could be useful ;-). I think LAStools has such tool.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**:

> Essentially, I am looking to remove the overlapping points so as to produce a homogeneous point cloud with no scanline overlaps.

Besides thinning ([Thinning large LiDAR point cloud?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173540/thinning-large-lidar-point-cloud)), if the .las file **is classified (or flagged) as 'overlapping' points** one can filter those out on-the-fly while importing data in R.

- For versions LAS 1.0 to 1.3 (point formats 0 to 5) overlapping points have their own class code, usually class 12. They can be filtered out with `-drop_class 12` as reported in your answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270961/open-source-approach-to-classifying-and-removing-lidar-points-from-overlapping-s/272949#272949).
- For version LAS 1.4 (point formats 6 to 10), it was introduced a group of classification flags, being one of them `Overlap`. This flag allows points to be flagged 'overlap' while also labeled with a different class code. For example, it can be an overlapping point (flagged) and a ground point (class 2). For those types of files, do the following*:

```
library(lidR) 
file.path <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
lidar <- readLAS(file.path, filter = "-drop_overlap") #LAS 1.4 (point formats 6 to 10) which has overlapping points set to 1 in the Classification Flag 'Overlap'.
```

Other methods and software for removing overlapping points are reported in [Open source approach to classifying and removing LiDAR points from overlapping scans?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270961/open-source-approach-to-classifying-and-removing-lidar-points-from-overlapping-s)

---

**Original answer**:

> How to filter point cloud by flightline in R?

As pointed by [JRR's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272249/how-to-filter-point-cloud-by-flightline-in-r/272289#272289), it is not possible yet using native filters from `readLAS` function available in the `lidR` package (see `rlas:::lasfilterusage()`).

So, the current alternative is to use `lasfilter`. See below:

```
library(lidR) 
file.path <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
lidar <- readLAS(file.path)
lasflightline(lidar, dt = 30)
#check how many flight lines (there should be at least two, so this exercise makes sense)
unique(lidar@data$flightlineID)

for (i in c(1:2)){
assign(paste("lidar.flightline.",i,sep=""), lasfilter(lidar, flightlineID == i))
}

rm(file.path,i,lidar)
```

Answer (score 0):

As my `ALS`dataset is not classified containing overlapping points, I thought a way of using @AndreSilva flightline filtering.
I created a function with the package `[lidR][1](2.2.2)` that what it does is to divide the `las` file into `chunks`, checks if the points in that `chunk` come from more than one flightline and if so, filters the point so the most represented flightline remains. It needs a quite small chunk sizes for good results which makes it very slow but maybe there is someone out there that can think in how to make it quicker.

```
library(lidR)
library(future)
plan(multisession, workers = 12L)
set_lidr_threads(12L)

path = "path to folder with data"
ctg <- readLAScatalog(path)

cuts = c(0,3,6,9,12,15,30)

dens0<-grid_density(ctg_1, res = 5)                       #Calculate for checking
plot(dens0,breaks=cuts,col=rainbow(12))

opt_chunk_size(ctg_1) <- 20                               # Needs to be small for precission
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg_1) <- 0                              
opt_output_files(ctg_1) <- paste0(tempfile(), "_{ID}")

myfun = function(cluster)
{
  las = readLAS(cluster)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)

  if (length((unique(las$PointSourceID)))>1){             # If there are more than 1 flightline in a chunk:

    table <- table(las@data$PointSourceID)#---------------#
    table <- sort(table , decreasing=T)                   #
    table <- as.data.frame(table)                         # Obtain as an INTEGER the
    table$Var1 <- as.character(table$Var1)                # most represented flightline in a chunk
    table$Var1 <- as.numeric(table$Var1)                  #
    most <- table$Var1[1]#--------------------------------#

    las <- lasfilter(las, PointSourceID == most)          # Only remains most represented flightline 
    return(las)
  }  else {return(las)}                                   # If there is only 1 flightline in a chunk

}

output <-catalog_sapply(ctg_1, myfun)                     # Apply function to catalog

dens1<-grid_density(output, res = 5)                      # Calculate for checking
plot(dens1,breaks=cuts,col=rainbow(12))
```

The result is a `catalog` containing all the `chunks` which makes extremely slow further processing. The fastest way to solve this is to read the `ctg` as a `lasfile` (`readLAS(ctg)`) butis not suggested as the output can be unmanageable.

[image: Catalog grid density with overlapping of flightlines]
[image: Catalog grid density after applying function]

----------------------------EDIT---------------------------

Following the suggested approach of @JRR I made this code. The results are not as good as with the previous code (flightlines's boundaries are still noticeable) but it takes much less time.

```
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 250
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 0
opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste0(tempfile(), "_{ID}")

myfun.LAS = function(las)
{
  PSID <- grid_metrics(las, ~quantile(PointSourceID, probs = 0.99), 1)  #obtain most represented flighline in segments of 1m^2
  las <- lasmergespatial(las, PSID, "PSID")       #Add a new attribute to each point of the most represented PSID in the 1m^2 segment where it is
  las <- lasfilter(las, PointSourceID == PSID)    #filter cloud       
  las$PSID <- NULL

  return(las)
}

myfun.ctg = function(cluster)
{
  las = readLAS(cluster)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)

  las <- myfun.LAS(las)                        
  return(las)                                  
}

output <- catalog_apply(ctg, myfun.ctg)
output <- readLAScatalog(unlist(output))
```

[image: Result of the new function]

Comment: `opt_chunk_size` tells you that a chunk size above 250 is likely to be a bad idea and it is true. On overall your idea is not bad but you should use `grid_metrics` to get the most represented flightline then `lasmergespatial` + `lasfilter` to remove the overlaping flightlines. Then you will be able to process meaningfull chunks or tiles.

Comment: I downvoted until you change this example for something more "workable". With a better implementation it may be a good anwser

Comment: I think I understood your approach. Similar to [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-catalog-apply-examples.html) if I am not wrong. I have applied this method but the result are not as good. You can check the "EDIT" part of my answer for the code

Comment: Your original option was "find the most represented point source ID in 20 x 20 pixel". You second option is "find the most represented PSI in 1 x 1 pixel with a quantile approach". The first attempt was a good idea, the second a correct implmentation. Try something like https://gist.github.com/Jean-Romain/40b4658c581a1b701c62d3f0bb4288dd

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I haven't created any metric yet for using it in `grid_metrics` so I just copied the vignette. I reduced the size of the segments because I found that when created a raster it did not work as good as when it looked within chunks of 20x20