# Filtering LAS Dataset and using output for raster conversion?

Tags: arcpy, dem, lidar, filter

I have problems with filtering LiDAR data within geoprocessing tools and python scripts. It simply doesn't work despite everyting looks correct. Filtering works only when I apply filter in properties of LAS dataset layer.

Here is an example of code which I'm using. I'm trying to filter only buildings class = 6. Sadly the result does not correspond to filter class values. In this example, result includes all classes unless I manualy filter LAS dataset in layer properties. Anyone had this problem?

```
# Process: Make LAS Dataset Layer
lasDatasetLayer = arcpy.MakeLasDatasetLayer_management(inputLasd, "LasDatasetLayer", 6, "", "false", "true", "true", "false", "")
# Process: LAS Dataset to Raster (2)
rasterFromLas = arcpy.LasDatasetToRaster_conversion(lasDatasetLayer, "rasterFromLas", "ELEVATION", "BINNING AVERAGE NONE", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", "1", "1")
```

I've read similar Q&As but they don't mention MakeLasDatasetLayer tool problems:

- [Specifying LAS dataset filters in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186551)
- [LAS dataset to raster with ground points only](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134542)

Comment: Thanks for replay @AndreSilva Saving didn't help. Saved *.lyr layer is not filtered. Looks like this Make LAS dataset layer tool works only within ArcMap?! I'm still missing something