# Specifying LAS dataset filters in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, lidar, lasd

I'm trying to create a tool in the ArcMap **ModelBuilder** to extract a canopy height raster from LiDAR data. I need to create rasters for ground elevation and first return. I've got my LAS dataset, and the "Filter" option on the LAS dataset toolbar allows me to select whether to display/use the **ground points, first return points**, etc.

I want to be able to do this in ModelBuilder - to be able to automatically create rasters for ground and first return. **But I can't figure out how to specify these filters in the LAS Dataset to Raster tool or in the properties of the input LAS datasets themselves**.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I have problems with filtering LIDAR data within geoprocessing tools and python scripts. It simply doesn't work despite everyting looks correct. Filtering works only when I apply filter in properties of LAS dataset layer. Here is example of code which I'm using. I'm trying to filter only buildings class = 6. Sadly the result does not correspond to filter class values. In this example, result includes all classes unless I manualy filter LAS dataset in layer properties. Anyone had this problem? # Process: Make LAS Dataset Layer lasDatasetLayer = arcpy.MakeLasDatasetLayer_management(inputLasd, "L

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/128176)

Answer (score 4):

You can't set filters in the [LAS Dataset to Raster Tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/las-dataset-to-raster.htm).

You can set them using the [Make LAS Dataset Layer Tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-las-dataset-layer.htm), then connect the output from this tool to the [LAS Dataset to Raster Tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/las-dataset-to-raster.htm).