# Selecting LiDAR return point type in LiDAR dataset with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, dem, lidar, arcgis-pro, filter

I am trying to create a Digital Earth Model (DEM) using ArcPy under ArcGIS Pro 2, but I am running into some problems.

I can generate a DEM within ArcGIS Pro by selecting only the ground points under LAS files in the LAS dataset properties, but when I try to run the same code within ArcPy, it generates a DEM using all the points.

Any ideas how you select the return point type in ArcPy?

Here is the code that I have used.

```
arcpy.conversion.LasDatasetToRaster(lasd, "Test_arcpy_dem", "ELEVATION", "BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", 10, 1)
```

As I said, this generates two different outputs, depending if I am in ArcGIS Pro or not.

Comment: You need to create a LAS Dataset Layer http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-las-dataset-layer.htm to restrict the class codes then use that layer in your LAS dataset to raster. The workflow is the same in desktop http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000151000000 to create a layer then use that layer in LAS dataset to raster http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000052000000

Comment: That worked perfectly. If you add your comment as an answer, I will select it.

Comment: Here is the code that I used based on suggestions from @MichaelStimson. `classCodes = [2];
return_Vals = ['Last Return','First of Many','Last of Many','Single Return','1','2','3','4'];
dem_layer = arcpy.CreateUniqueName('dem_layer') ## new LAS dataset layer name;
arcpy.MakeLasDatasetLayer_management(lasd, dem_layer,class_code=classCodes,return_values=return_Vals);
arcpy.conversion.LasDatasetToRaster(dem_layer, "DEM", "ELEVATION", "BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", 10, 1);` Note: I marked end of line with semi-colon. Not needed.

Comment: Did that work for you? By default return_values is *everything* so I think that parameter can be omitted, apart from that it looks good.

Comment: It did work for me. If you post it as the answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you're working in ArcGIS Pro or Desktop to restrict the class types to ground classes (2 and 8 if present) you need to [create a LAS dataset layer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-las-dataset-layer.htm):

```
arcpy.MakeLasDatasetLayer_management(lasd, "LASD_Layer",class_code=[2,8])
```

which you can use in your [LAS dataset to raster function](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/las-dataset-to-raster.htm):

```
arcpy.conversion.LasDatasetToRaster("LASD_Layer", "Test_arcpy_dem", "ELEVATION", "BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", 10, 1)
```

In Desktop: [create a LAS dataset layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000151000000) and [LAS dataset to raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000052000000).

If you don't already have ground/nonground classes you can use [Classify LAS Ground](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/classify-las-ground.htm) ([also in ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/classify-las-ground.htm)) by Esri or a similar tool to classify ground in your LiDAR point cloud; automatic classification of ground/nonground is usually quite successful, unlike automatic building classification but that's wandering off-topic.

Comment: How is the last line modified to accept a different interpolation method? I am not sure if that is how it is done but I replaced the `BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR` with `IDW` and `INVERSE DISTANCE WEIGHTED` and got the error `ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (LAS Dataset To Raster). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter interpolation_type`. I also tried to determine the accuracy of the dtm using `output_prediction_error = True` but this gives the error. Any idea how I can work around?

Comment: @Nasa_Milla I'm not sure, I've yet to work directly with ArcGIS Pro, perhaps try adding a void fill method as per the docs https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/las-dataset-to-raster.htm "IDW NATURAL_NEIGHBOR" sounds like it would work.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I modified the interpolation method to `BINNING IDW LINEAR` and it now works.