# Separating LAS Dataset (.lasd) into point files of each class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, point, lidar, filter

I am want to examine my DEM, DSM, and other models I'm generating from LiDAR data in the model wizard to find the method with the least amount of error.

I want to separate the ground, and non-ground points into separate point shapefiles so I can use them within the model wizard and view the error and generate the error prediction surfaces as well as view the semi-variograms of different model parameters.

I would like to have points with the elevation value as a field within the point feature, and have a point feature for each class of the .lasd.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your LiDAR point cloud is already classified, use the [LAS To Multipoint](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/las-to-multipoint.htm) tool to both filter the point cloud (`class_code` parameter) and converting it to a (multi) point feature class (shapefile) in one go (use it once for each class code or group of class code).

Alternatively, you can filter with [Make LAS Dataset Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-las-dataset-layer.htm) tool, so to keep one lidar (.lasd) file per class (in case you need to do other processing tasks using the point cloud format), and then use `Las to Multipoint` only to convert to point feature class.

As concerning having elevation in the table of attributes (TOC) one option is the [Calculate Geomtetry](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm) tool. Take a look at [Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap in ArcMap but do not?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-in-arcmap-but-do-not/54601#54601) (items 5 and 6, to see an example).

---

You might be interested reading [Converting LiDAR data to raster (DEM/DSM) for ArcGIS input?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/converting-lidar-data-to-raster-dem-dsm-for-arcgis-input/56710#56710) as well.