# Generating DEM Generation in LPS?

Tags: qgis, dem, photogrammetry, leica-geo-office

I have a Cartosat 2.5 m Imagery and Block files along with DSM Data. I wanted to generate DEM using Leica Photogrammetry Suite Software. Does anyone know the steps of generating same?

I  have to edit the existing DSM by augmenting with more breaklines / masspoints and editing of existing points to the exact ground surface as visualized on the stereo data supplied.

Also is DSM also in black/white color or is there a way to change bands and update the colors?

How can I perform the same on LPS Software?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] the question to focus on one question ad provide more information on what you have attempted.

Comment: To address one part of your question ("is DSM also in black/white color"), a [DSM, or digital surface model,](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/differences-between-dem-dsm-and-dtm) is an elevation raster not a photograph, so black and white is expected. You can choose to display it in pseudocolor if you like, see [the QGIS Manual > working with rasters > style properties](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#style-properties).

Answer (score 0):

You want to edit DSM (vector format:ltfx, tin.pro) file in 3D stereo environment,
where you can change the color of your mass point, break line and create new to final convert into DEM (DTM).

You can enhance the B/W cartosat image for enhanced clear view.

Any issue in setting up your machine environment, 3D editing and let me know.