# Compare two Digital Elevation Model (DEM)

Tags: python, dem, c++, comparison

I would like to know what's the best method(s) to compare two DEMs without using any GUI soft like QGIS or ArcGIS.
I'd like to do it in Python or C++, with GDAL or other similar lib.
Does calculating the RMSE (Root mean square error/deviation) is useful?
How to proceed to subtract DEM1 from DEM2? And I should find a flat result, right?
Is their other ways?
Because reading for each coordinate the elevation `z` and compare it with the other DEM is a bit heavy I think.

Thanks for help,
eo

Comment: How else would you subtract A from B without comparing each cell?

Comment: Don't know, you're right...

Comment: A GDAL tool would be gdallocationinfo, where you can pull each pixel from the DEMs in turn.
I'd rather do it in R.
What do you mean by "compare"? You want to see the differences as an image? 
You want to have a "similarity value" to compare multiple dems pairwise?
Do you know more about your DEMs, e.g. the acquisition method, the type (DSM or DTM)?

Comment: Ok thx. No I need to compare them in order to knoz if they represent the same terrain. So if the second DEM is in line with the first one (i.e. same hilly terrain, same flat zones...)

Comment: Most DEMs come with a georeferencing (corner coordinates for example). Do yours have those? So, you are not interested in coregistering the images ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration ), you just want a "yes, they show the same area / no, they show different areas"?

Comment: No... I don't use DEM from the real world. It's generated DEM for simulation purposes

Comment: For some methods and insights, you might be interested in reading through a [recent case study](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/56573).  Subtracting one DEM from the other (which is quick and easy) is only the very beginning: there will be differences that you have to explore, measure, and seek to understand.  Computing the RMSE has its place, but as a single number it's not going to tell you much about how the DEMs differ.

Comment: +1 @whuber. Without knowing much about the DEMs (are they either identical or not identical?) I would think you'd need to consider more than just the difference between matching pixel values. A more in-depth analysis of slope (or other metrics) across a neighborhood would yield more information. To start you can use R for the programmatic calculations and GRASS/GDAL for the file handling without using the GUIs.

Comment: @Radar Yes, slope is important. But you don't need `R` for these calculations: much (maybe most) of what is needed can be accomplished with relatively simple "map algebra" calculations available in ArcGIS/Spatial Analyst or GRASS, for instance.  I would recommend `R` when analytical needs are sophisticated and the DEM is relatively small (perhaps a million cells or less), but for large DEMs you need the efficiency of a raster-based GIS (which `R` is definitely not).

Comment: Fair enough - though I am under the impression that ArcGIS is off the table. A Python script utilizing GRASS may be the best approach then if R will be too inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for your advices guys. Yes I'm gonna write a Python script. Do you have some names or clues about spatial statistics I could compute on my DEMs?

Answer (score 3):

There's a similar [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/comparing-two-dems), but not doing it with a programming language.

here's a small python snippet which checks the difference between two numpy matrixes.

```
a = np.random.randint(-10,400,(500,500))      # or gdal.Open("path/to/raster").GetRasterBand(0).ReadAsArray()
b = np.random.randint(-10,400,(500,500))
dif = abs((a-b)/(b+1e-5))<0.05                # Returns a T/F matrix if difference is more than 5%. 
                                              # I add 1e-5 at the denominator to avoid div by zero
float(np.count_nonzero(tf))/len(tf.flatten()) # Ratio between Trues vs length of matrix
```